# C# Excel generating

Tags: c#, asp.net, epplus

I am genearting excel bar chart from Epplus libary.

This is is what I have successfully genearted.

[image]
My table lokks like this

```
                 Mumbai         Delhi
Financial Dailies   103     279
Mainlines Dailies   35      55
Periodicals         0       6
Regional Dailies    68      212
```

What I am stuck with is how to add color coded legend on left side of chart as I have drawn in Pic-2 below.

**Mumbai** and **Delhi** are the **column names** of the table from which i am populating the chart.

[image]

code is below

```
protected void addBarGraph(string r1,string r2,string r3,string r4)
{

    try{


    var chart1 = ws.Drawings.AddChart("xyz",eChartType.ColumnClustered3D) as ExcelBarChart ;

    chart1.SetPosition(1, 0, 1, 0);
    chart1.SetSize(600, 400);

  // chart1.Legend.Position = OfficeOpenXml.Drawing.Chart.eLegendPosition.Left;
   chart1.DataLabel.ShowValue = true;
   // chart1.DataLabel.ShowLegendKey = true;
    //chart1.DataLabel.ShowLeaderLines = true;

   // chart1.DataLabel.ShowSeriesName = true;
   // chart1.Legend.ToString();

  //  chart1.Legend.Add();


    chart1.Series.Add(r1, r2);
    chart1.Series.Add(r3, r2);
    chart1.Series.Add(r4, r2);

    chart1.Style = OfficeOpenXml.Drawing.Chart.eChartStyle.Style26;
    chart1.Title.Text = "Some title";
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write(ex.Message);
    }

}
```

Please help me out .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Header property.

```
        var serie1 = chart1.Series.Add(r1, r2);
        serie1.Header = "Mumbai";
        var serie2 = chart1.Series.Add(r3, r2);
        serie2.Header = "Delhi";
```